# Playing Mono encoded audio out rear channels through SlimDX XAudio2 when Sound Card only reports Channel Mask of 3

Tags: c#, playback, channel, directsound, xaudio2

I had an older system (XP) that allowed me to play mono encoded PCM audio out the rear channels (back right and/or back left) through DirectX using a DirectSoundBuffer and WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE object with the ChannelMask Set for Back Speakers.

I am trying to redo the same functionality on the old system as well and a new system with .Net and SlimDx XAudio2 but when I Call SetOutputMatrix on the old system it ignores everything I set for anything but the Front left and right Channels even though the sound card is set for 5.1 surround sound.  On the new system it works fine.  When I call GetDeviceDetails on the old system it reports that the channelmask is 3 (only front two speakers).  I am guessing that is why it only allows me to play out the front even though the old C++ DirectSound worked.  I am guessing the sound driver is in error but I can't find any updates for this.

Is there a workaround for this?

Here is a sample from the XAudio2 C++ Basic Sound Demo that has the same behavior

```
if( FAILED( hr = XAudio2Create( &pXAudio2, flags ) ) )
{
    wprintf( L"Failed to init XAudio2 engine: %#X\n", hr );
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}

UINT32 devCount;

hr = pXAudio2->GetDeviceCount(&devCount);

XAUDIO2_DEVICE_DETAILS devDetails;

hr = pXAudio2->GetDeviceDetails(0, &devDetails);
```

Here when I get the Device Details the ChannelMask is 3 (Front speakers) even though the SoundCard configuration is set for 5.1.  The soundcard is an old SoundMax AC'97 card. Later on when I do the following:

```
float fMatrix[6] = {0};

pSourceVoice->GetOutputMatrix(pMasteringVoice, 1, 6, fMatrix);

fMatrix[0] = 0.0;
fMatrix[1] = 1.0;
fMatrix[2] = 1.0;
fMatrix[3] = 1.0;
fMatrix[4] = 1.0;
fMatrix[5] = 1.0;

hr = pSourceVoice->SetOutputMatrix(NULL,1,6, fMatrix);


pSourceVoice->GetOutputMatrix(pMasteringVoice, 1, 6, fMatrix);
```

After the first GetOutputMatrix the fMatrix is has [0] and [1] indexes set to 1.0.  When I call SetOutputMatrix I am trying to set other channels to 1.0 but after the GetOutputMatrix the fMatrix only has [1] set to 1.0.  Everything else is 0.

NOTE:  When calling SetOutputMatrix and it doesn't set all the values it doesn't fail, it returns OK.

Comment: Can you add code samples please?

Comment: The answer for this was that the new machine had a bad driver and only supported Front L and Front R (Even though I set it as 7.1 surround)